# Calling Rest API causing Unprocessable Entity (422) in Java

Tags: java, php, rest

I have a rest API build in php. I am calling that in my java application. When parsing data it gives me Unprocessable Entity (422). The same API with the same data is working absolutely fine. but when I deploy my jar on test server it is causing this. I checked JSON and its same as in my local. Below is the sample JSON, incase that will help you to give any direction.

Thanks in advance.

```
{"units":[{"position":{"latitude":52.5218136,"longitude":13.432295},"parkingSpaceId":"5bebfc18ec045b36418b4569","capacity":180,"currentWeight":180,"name":"100095 Textil DRK beige","labelId":"100095","properties":{"contactSettings":{"eventNotificationSettings":{"workingTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true},"offTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true}},"global":true},"timeSettings":{"global":true},"parameters":{"global":true},"forbiddenHarbors":{"harbors":[],"global":true},"forbiddenCountries":{"countries":[],"global":true}},"id":"5c0e8126ec045b53168b459b"},{"position":{"latitude":52.5453222,"longitude":13.5642258},"parkingSpaceId":"5bebf65fec045beb4e8b459b","capacity":180,"currentWeight":180,"name":"100162 Textil DRK weiß","labelId":"100162","properties":{"contactSettings":{"eventNotificationSettings":{"workingTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true},"offTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true}},"global":true},"timeSettings":{"global":true},"parameters":{"global":true},"forbiddenHarbors":{"harbors":[],"global":true},"forbiddenCountries":{"countries":[],"global":true}},"id":"5c0e7f7eec045b51168b4576"},{"position":{"latitude":52.5401149,"longitude":13.5671104},"parkingSpaceId":"5bebfff6ec045bf0418b4572","capacity":180,"currentWeight":180,"name":"100340 Textil RETEX HD","labelId":"100340","properties":{"contactSettings":{"eventNotificationSettings":{"workingTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true},"offTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true}},"global":true},"timeSettings":{"global":true},"parameters":{"global":true},"forbiddenHarbors":{"harbors":[],"global":true},"forbiddenCountries":{"countries":[],"global":true}},"id":"5c0e82e4ec045be9148b45af"},{"position":{"latitude":52.4255217,"longitude":13.4827826},"parkingSpaceId":"5bebfc4bec045b2b418b4569","capacity":180,"currentWeight":108,"name":"101386 Textil DRK weiß","labelId":"101386","properties":{"contactSettings":{"eventNotificationSettings":{"workingTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true},"offTime":{"harborEntered":{"contacts":[]},"forbiddenCountries":{"contacts":[]},"periodOfUsePassed":{"contacts":[]},"mileagePassed":{"contacts":[]},"powercut":{"contacts":[]},"mileageReached":{"contacts":[]},"operatingBehavior":{"contacts":[]},"routines":{"contacts":[]},"vandalism":{"contacts":[]},"unplannedDoorOpening":{"contacts":[]},"malfunction":{"contacts":[]},"relocation":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"emptyingOverdue":{"contacts":[]},"batteryReplacementUpcoming":{"contacts":[]},"batteryConditionCritical":{"contacts":[]},"global":true}},"global":true},"timeSettings":{"global":true},"parameters":{"global":true},"forbiddenHarbors":{"harbors":[],"global":true},"forbiddenCountries":{"countries":[],"global":true}},"id":"5c0e8140ec045b59168b459c"}],"limit":"5"}
```

Java Code:

```
ClientResource resource = getResource(
            String.format("%s/internal/unitbases?companyId=" + id + "&limit=10", apiPrefix));
    try {
        Units units = resource.get(Units.class);
        List<Location> locationListForCompany = units.getUnits();
        return locationListForCompany;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception occur: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```